# malloc(): corrupted top size for matrix inverse

Tags: c, matrix, malloc, matrix-inverse

I am trying to create a matrix calculator and when I try to use the inverse function I get an error saying "malloc(): corrupted top size". I do not know what this error means and how to fix it.

This is my code:

```
double** inverse(double *mat[], int n){
    //identity matrix
    double **I = malloc(sizeof(double*) * n);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) I[i] = malloc(sizeof(double) * n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
            if(i==j){
                I[i][j] = 1;
            }else{
                I[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
        
    double f = 0.0;
    double sub = 0.0;
    for(int p=0; p<n; n++){
        f = mat[p][p];
        for(int x=0; x<n; x++){
            mat[p][x] = mat[p][x] / f;
            I[p][x] = I[p][x] / f; (line 45)
        } 
        for(int i=p+1; i<n; i++){
            f = mat[i][p]; (line 48)
            for(int x=0; x<n; x++){
                sub = mat[p][x] * f;
                mat[i][x] = mat[i][x] - sub; (line 51)
                    
                sub = I[p][x] * f;       
                I[i][x] = I[i][x] - sub; (line 54)
            }
        }
    }
        
    for(int p=n-1; p>=0; p--){
        for(int i=p-1; i>=0; i--){
            f = mat[i][p];
            for(int x=0; x<n; x++){
                sub = mat[p][x] * f;
                mat[i][x] = mat[i][x] - sub;
                    
                sub = I[p][x] * f;
                I[i][x] = I[i][x] - sub;
            }
        }
    }
    //return I;
    printf("I:\n");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
            printf("%f ",I[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
        
    //free
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) free(I[i]);
    free(I);
}

void multiply(double *mat1[], double *mat2[], int R1, int C1, int R2, int C2, double *rslt[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < R1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < C2; j++) {
            rslt[i][j] = 0;
 
            for (int k = 0; k < R2; k++) {
                rslt[i][j] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j];
            }
            printf("%f\t", rslt[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    //return rslt;
}

int main(){
    double **rslt = malloc(sizeof(double*) * n);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) rslt[i] = malloc(sizeof(double) * (k+1));
    multiply(x,t,n,k+1,k+1,n,rslt);
    /* x and t are matrices, n=7, k+1=5,(these are the matrix dimensions for x, and the opposite are the matrix dimensions for t) */
    /* the variables in the call to multiply(x and t are matrices, n and k+1 are
       matrix dimensions, and rslt stores the result) are declared and cause no errors*/
    /* the code works with no errors upto this point*/

    /* rslt is the resulting matrix after the call to the multiply function
       and n is the matrix dimensions */
    inverse(rslt,n);
}
```

I am trying to find the inverse after multiplying two matrices. The code uses the "rslt" matrix which holds the product and calls the inverse function. The multiply functions works perfectly and I only get an error after the call to "inverse()".

After running valgrind it shows me that the error occurs in the inverse function. It seems to occur multiple times in the for loops when I try to access the matrices. It says the leaks are in lines 45, 48, 51, and 54(I specified which lines they are above). The specific error valgrind shows me is "Invalid read of size 8" and "Invalid write of size 8".

Comment: It's possible that `multiply()` has a bug that causes heap corruption. It doesn't get noticed until `inverse()` calls `malloc()`.

Comment: Try running your program with `valgrind`.

Comment: `free(I); for (int i=0; i<n; i++) free(I[i]);` You need to flip this order. `I[i]` isn't allowed after you `free(I);` Treat your `malloc`s and `free`s as a LIFO stack.

Comment: @yano I did that and I still get the same error.

Comment: @Barmar How do I run my program with `valgrind`.

Comment: Other problems then. A [mre] would be most helpful.

Comment: @Barmar I edited my question and added `multiply()`.

Comment: `sizeof(double) * k+1` should be `sizeof(double) * (k+1)`

Comment: @Barmar I still get the same error.

Comment: To clarify, I mean, I mean only apply "Treat your `mallloc`s and `free`s as a LIFO stack" to the double pointer paradigm. `T** t = malloc(sizeof(*t) * n); for(i=0; i<n; i++){ t[i] = malloc(...); }`, you need to "unwind" in the opposite direction when you `free`: `for(i=0; i<n; i++){ free(t[i]); } free(t);`.

Comment: Valgrind tutorial: http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/valgrind/

Comment: @yano Yeah, I did that and it still caused an error for some reason.

Comment: @Barmar After running `valgrind` it shows me that the leak occurs in the inverse function. It seems to occur multiple times in the for loops when I try to access the matrices. I edited the question with the specific line numbers the program says has leaks.

Comment: Leaks don't cause errors like this.

Comment: This error comes from writing to unallocated memory, indirecting through uninitialized pointers, etc.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah sorry I meant to specify that the error is cause by an invalid read/write of size 8 in the loop.

Comment: `x, t, n, k`  What are they?

Comment: Which lines are `45`, `48`, 51, and 54`.

Comment: Since no answers have been posted yet, you can edit the code and fix the bugs  already pointed out.

Comment: "invalid read" means you're reading uninitialized data or data that has been freed.

Comment: @Barmar I do not see how that could happen in my loop since everything has been initialized. And all my free statements occur at the end of the function.

Comment: Unrelated: `double** inverse(double *mat[], int n){` but the function never returns a value. Should it be `void inverse(double *mat[], int n){`

Comment: We still need x, t, n, k

Comment: @4386427 I specified the values in the code just now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you multiply a R1xC1 matrix with a R2xC2 (where C1 must equal R2), you'll get a R1xC2 matrix.

But you don't allocate that for the result.

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) rslt[i] = malloc(sizeof(double) * (k+1))
multiply(x,t,n,k+1,k+1,n,rslt);                           ^^^^^
             ^         ^                                  wrong
             R1        C2
```

So here

```
void multiply(double *mat1[], double *mat2[], int R1, int C1, int R2, int C2, double *rslt[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < R1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < C2; j++) {
            rslt[i][j] = 0;
```

you write outside the allocated memory (because `n` is bigger than `k+1`).

You want to do

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) rslt[i] = malloc(sizeof(double) * n)
                                                          ^
                                                        notice
```